# How to download a file from url without saving it to disk?

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I am trying to download files from urls and upload them to S3 buckets in AWS. My best approach so far is saving the file to the temp folder in the disk and delete it after uploading it to S3 bucket.

This is how I do it:

```
private File downloadFileFromUrl(String fileUrlToUpload) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(fileUrlToUpload);
        String tempDir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
        File file = new File(tempDir + FilenameUtils.getName(url.getPath()));
        FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, file);
        return file;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Could not download file from: {}!", fileUrlToUpload);
        return null;
    }
}
```

And then delete the file after uploading it in the service which calls **downloadFileFromUrl** method.

However, I am looking for a way to download a file from url and upload it directly to S3 bucket without saving it to the disk. I am not even sure if this is a better approach, but it seems cleaner solution than saving something to the disk.

I am also open to other approaches. Thanks!

Comment: is your file too big?

Comment: Not that big. They are about 100kb each. I saw multipart file upload feature of AWS but I am not going to upload large files.

Comment: then you do not need to create file, store into bytes and pass to S3 bucket. and see @Vusal answer.

Answer (score 3):

Probably, in this case, the best approach is to use [AWS Signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html) to upload and download the file - instead of serving as a proxy.

If you insist on downloading the file yourself, you can do the following:

```
BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
while ((buffer = bufferedInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    sb.append(new String(buffer));
}
```

`sb` - contains contents of the file.

You can also use [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html):

```
IOUtils.toString(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
```

Comment: Is not AWS Signed URL used to fetch the existing files in S3 Bucket? Is it also used to upload new files?

Comment: @ahmetcetin and also for upload, read [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html) please.

Comment: I could upload a file using AWS Signed URL, but I still need to download it @Vusal. Do you know how to pass the url directly as a file?

Comment: @ahmetcetin you can download and upload files using AWS signed URLs. Please, follow links specified in the answer and in the comments. If you want to download them without using AWS signed URLs - I answered this question as well. From the aforementioned link: [Upload an Object Using a Presigned URL (AWS SDK for Java)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObjectJavaSDK.html)

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately, this did not solve my problem. I still need to create the file object in my disk.

Comment: You can generate the URL and pass it to the client - so your client will upload the file. You don't need to upload file yourself. "I still need to create the file object in my disk." - you don't need. As I stated in the answer - you can store the whole file in String object and then upload it to S3 if you have a URL object (see while loop or `IOUtils.toString`).